# Set a form input to dirty in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a form that I auto input the current date into an input field. I want to set the input field to dirty because when it tries to sync with firebase, that input field is not included unless you interact with it.

I have tried the following in many different forms...and I am at a loss.

```js
var now = new Date();
  $scope.load = function () {
    if (!$rootScope.auth) {
      $location.path('/a/');
    } else {
      $scope.logs = Logs.list($scope);
      $scope.newDate = now;
      $scope.logForm.$setDirty(true);
    }
  };
```

```
<form name="logForm" novalidate class="css-form">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="action" placeholder="Action" type="text" value="{{newAction}}" ng-model="newAction" required />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" type="number" value="{{newQuantity}}" ng-model="newQuantity" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="location" placeholder="Location" type="text" value="{{newLocation}}" ng-model="newLocation" />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Date" type="datetime" value="{{newDate}}" ng-model="newDate" />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="create()">Add log</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: If the input field is in `logForm`, you should be able to access it by `$scope.logForm[<name of form input>]`. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yep! I get `Cannot call method '$setDirty' of undefined`.

Comment: Strange, could you provide the used html templates?

Comment: Done, what do you think?

Comment: is likely because controller fires before digest cycle goes through form to add form object and models to scope. Might try `ng-init`. Likely able to set value and avoid the `$dirty` part

Comment: Thats actually how I am doing it. its in a `div` just outside of the form. The js posted above is actually in that `load()` function.

Comment: ok, but if form object not created...need to try your dirty tricks in the form with `ng-init`. not sure how cycle works, but have to assume as soon as form tag encountered, the form object gets created

Comment: ok I moved `ng-init` into the `form` tag and it still isn't working

Comment: Actually...have you tried pulling `$scope.newDate = now;` out of your `load()` and put it directly into controller scope? create a demo in plunker

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I don't think I can make a plunker because of my dependencies, and as far as I know this is only happening with firebase. So if I made a plunker I would be publishing my firebase credentials too.

Comment: what is the exact problem that need to interact with form to get data sent? Creating object that contains all the models as peaceman suggests would likely help bind to whatever object firebase needs...I've never used firebase

Answer (score 1):

The `form` tag creates its own scope, so to have a reliable scope structure, we shouldn't use primitives for the `ng-model` values.

To ensure, that we have access to the form controller, we have to delay the form initialization into the next digest cycle. This is achieved with the use of the `$timeout` service.

http://jsbin.com/OvIvIHO/3/

jsbin contains the updated version

Comment: since when is date object a primitive?

Comment: So I don't really understand what you mean. That jsbin has the same results as mine. when you set the date in the input box, it still stays pristine.

Comment: @charlietfl hmm, primitive might be the wrong term. But it is about the creation of the child scopes as described at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#wiki-JSproto

Comment: @peaceman if directives on inputs or ancestorrs within form were involved would understand....however, `ng-model` has no problem binding directly to a primitive if input is still in scope of controller. Agree that objects are best to use...but date object would circumvent all that anyway

Comment: @charlietfl it surely is a best practice, as it also makes it easier to work with the form data

Comment: @Tyler.Exposure yeah i mixed up the debug outputs, but the currently linked jsbin should work

Comment: so is it the timeout that actually does it?

Comment: here's same result putting `ng-init="logForm.$setDirty()"` on form tag and setting date directly in controller...http://jsbin.com/OvIvIHO/4/edit